# React Bootstrap Progress Bar Computed Color

Tags: reactjs, progress-bar, react-bootstrap

How would I go about dynamically setting the React Bootstrap Progress Bar background color?

My attempts to edit the inner generated 'progress-bar' class have been unsuccessful. The following code will correctly set the height to 250 but the background color remains the default blue color.

```
import React from 'react';
import ProgressBar from 'react-bootstrap/ProgressBar';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';

const styles = {
    progressBar: {
        height: 250,
        '& progress-bar': {
            backgroundColor: 'black'
        },
    }
}

const ProgressBarCustom = (props) => {     
    const classes = props.classes;
    return <ProgressBar className={classes.progressBar} now={props.sliderValue} label={props.valueLabel} />
}

export default withStyles(styles)(ProgressBarCustom);
```

Each progress bar will eventually have a computed color value, so I cannot simply edit the css stylesheet that bootstrap is using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

`.progress-bar` is a class. You need to use the class selector `.`

```
const styles = {
  progressBar: {
      height: 250,
      '& .progress-bar': { /* add the period */
          backgroundColor: 'black'
      },
  }
}
```

---

As a side note, you can also utilize the `variant` prop of the [react-bootstrap progress bar](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/progress/#progress-contextual). Examples:

```
<ProgressBar variant="warning" now={60} />
<ProgressBar variant="danger" now={80} />
```

react-bootstrap readily provides you the themes for the progress bars